# Как сделать связь между таблицами один к одному?

Tags: sql, oracle

Eсть одна таблица (A):

```
Id Name 
-- --------
1  Pasport
2  ID Card
```

Xочу создать еще одну таблицу, которая будет связана с таблицей A один к одному.

Например:

```
CREATE TABLE B (
   ID NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
   NAME VARCHAR2(128)
)
```

Kак это сделать ?

Comment: Задача искусственная. На практике такая связь почти никогда не используется. Разве что достигнуто ограничение на количество полей (атрибутов).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте вот так:

```
create table a (
    id number(5) primary key, 
    name varchar2 (128))
/    
create table b (
   id number(5) not null unique references a (id),
   name varchar2 (128))
/
```

Ограничение `unique` обеспечит связь один-к-одному, а заодно, добавит индекс для внешнего ключа, который не создаётся автоматически.

Comment: Pasport И ID_Card это записи в Table

Comment: @TeonaNadiradze Извините, ожидал информацию по таблице, а не данные.  Поправил.